# How to make a 5-Player Guessing Game(Basic)

Tags: java, swing

Im experiencing errors in this code. this is our case study so we need to create this program using only javax.swing,do-while,and if else.

**==my code seems to be working only until Player 3. when i type player  4 and 5, it just terminates.==**

anythin' wrong? because eclipse ain't saying stuff. my professor said something about making this a "loop within a loop" instead of copy-paste if else, but im having a hard time figuring it out...

**I only need a fix in the 4th and 5th player error....**

Thanks in Advance

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class CaseStudyHW {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int guess;
        int magic = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        int attempt1 = 1;
        int attempt2 = 1;
        int attempt3 = 1;
        int attempt4 = 1;
        int attempt5 = 1;
        int players;

        players = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Number of Players. \n2-5 Only"));
        if (players == 2) {
            do {
                guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Player 1, Enter A Number from 1-10", "Guessing Game", 1));
                if (guess == magic) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! You Guessed the Magic Number!"
                            + "\nThe Number is " + magic + "\nYou Made a Total of " + attempt1 + " attempt(s)", "Guessing Game", 1);
                } else {
                    attempt1++;
                    if (guess > magic) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is higher than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is lower than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                    }
                }
            } while (guess != magic);

            do {
                guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Player 2, Enter A Number from 1-10", "Guessing Game", 1));

                if (guess == magic) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! You Guessed the Magic Number!"
                            + "\nThe Number is " + magic + "\nYou Made a Total of " + attempt2 + " attempt(s)", "Guessing Game", 1);
                } else {
                    attempt2++;
                    if (guess > magic) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is higher than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0
                        );
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is lower than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                    }
                }
            } while (guess != magic);
            if (attempt1 > attempt2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 1 Won!", "Guessing Game", 0);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 2 Won!", "Guessing Game", 0);
            }
        } else if (players == 3) {
            do {
                guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Player 1, Enter A Number from 1-10", "Guessing Game", 1));

                if (guess == magic) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! You Guessed the Magic Number!"
                            + "\nThe Number is " + magic + "\nYou Made a Total of " + attempt1 + " attempt(s)", "Guessing Game", 1);
                } else {
                    attempt1++;
                    if (guess > magic) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is higher than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0                        );
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is lower than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                    }
                }
            } while (guess != magic);

            do {
                guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,                        "Player 2, Enter A Number from 1-10", "Guessing Game", 1));

                if (guess == magic) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! You Guessed the Magic Number!"
                            + "\nThe Number is " + magic + "\nYou Made a Total of " + attempt2 + " attempt(s)", "Guessing Game", 1);
                } else {
                    attempt2++;
                    if (guess > magic) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is higher than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0
                        );
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is lower than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                    }
                }
            } while (guess != magic);

            do {
                guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                        "Player 3, Enter A Number from 1-10", "Guessing Game", 1));

                if (guess == magic) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! You Guessed the Magic Number!"
                            + "\nThe Number is " + magic + "\nYou Made a Total of " + attempt3 + " attempt(s)", "Guessing Game", 1);
                } else {
                    attempt3++;
                    if (guess > magic) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is higher than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0
                        );
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is lower than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                    }
                }
            } while (guess != magic);
            if (attempt1 > attempt2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 1 Won!", "Guessing Game", 0);
            } else if (attempt2 > attempt3) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 2 Won!", "Guessing Game", 0);
            } else if (attempt3 > attempt1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 3 Won!", "Guessing Game", 0);
            } else if (players == 4) {
                do {
                    guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                            "Player 1, Enter A Number from 1-10", "Guessing Game", 1));

                    if (guess == magic) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! You Guessed the Magic Number!"
                                + "\nThe Number is " + magic + "\nYou Made a Total of " + attempt1 + " attempt(s)", "Guessing Game", 1);
                    } else {
                        attempt1++;
                        if (guess > magic) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is higher than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0
                            );
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is lower than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                        }
                    }
                } while (guess != magic);

                do {
                    guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                            "Player 2, Enter A Number from 1-10", "Guessing Game", 1));

                    if (guess == magic) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! You Guessed the Magic Number!"
                                + "\nThe Number is " + magic + "\nYou Made a Total of " + attempt2 + " attempt(s)", "Guessing Game", 1);
                    } else {
                        attempt2++;
                        if (guess > magic) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is higher than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0
                            );
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is lower than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                        }
                    }
                } while (guess != magic);

                do {
                    guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                            "Player 3, Enter A Number from 1-10", "Guessing Game", 1));

                    if (guess == magic) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! You Guessed the Magic Number!"
                                + "\nThe Number is " + magic + "\nYou Made a Total of " + attempt3 + " attempt(s)", "Guessing Game", 1);
                    } else {
                        attempt3++;
                        if (guess > magic) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is higher than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0
                            );
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is lower than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                        }
                    }
                } while (guess != magic);

                do {
                    guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                            "Player 4, Enter A Number from 1-10", "Guessing Game", 1));

                    if (guess == magic) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! You Guessed the Magic Number!"
                                + "\nThe Number is " + magic + "\nYou Made a Total of " + attempt1 + " attempt(s)", "Guessing Game", 1);
                    } else {
                        attempt4++;
                        if (guess > magic) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is higher than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0
                            );
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is lower than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                        }
                    }
                } while (guess != magic);
                if (attempt1 > attempt2) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 1 Won!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                } else if (attempt2 > attempt3) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 2 Won!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                } else if (attempt3 > attempt1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 3 Won!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                } else if (attempt4 > attempt3) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 4 Won!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                } else if (players == 5) {
                    do {
                        guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                "Player 1, Enter A Number from 1-10", "Guessing Game", 1));

                        if (guess == magic) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! You Guessed the Magic Number!"
                                    + "\nThe Number is " + magic + "\nYou Made a Total of " + attempt1 + " attempt(s)", "Guessing Game", 1);
                        } else {
                            attempt1++;
                            if (guess > magic) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is higher than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0
                                );
                            } else {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is lower than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                            }
                        }
                    } while (guess != magic);

                    do {
                        guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                "Player 2, Enter A Number from 1-10", "Guessing Game", 1));

                        if (guess == magic) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! You Guessed the Magic Number!"
                                    + "\nThe Number is " + magic + "\nYou Made a Total of " + attempt2 + " attempt(s)", "Guessing Game", 1);
                        } else {
                            attempt2++;
                            if (guess > magic) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is higher than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0
                                );
                            } else {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is lower than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                            }
                        }
                    } while (guess != magic);

                    do {
                        guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                "Player 3, Enter A Number from 1-10", "Guessing Game", 1));

                        if (guess == magic) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! You Guessed the Magic Number!"
                                    + "\nThe Number is " + magic + "\nYou Made a Total of " + attempt3 + " attempt(s)", "Guessing Game", 1);
                        } else {
                            attempt3++;
                            if (guess > magic) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is higher than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0
                                );
                            } else {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is lower than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                            }
                        }
                    } while (guess != magic);

                    do {
                        guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                "Player 4, Enter A Number from 1-10", "Guessing Game", 1));

                        if (guess == magic) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! You Guessed the Magic Number!"
                                    + "\nThe Number is " + magic + "\nYou Made a Total of " + attempt1 + " attempt(s)", "Guessing Game", 1);
                        } else {
                            attempt4++;
                            if (guess > magic) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is higher than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0
                                );
                            } else {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is lower than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                            }
                        }
                    } while (guess != magic);

                    do {
                        guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                "Player 5, Enter A Number from 1-10", "Guessing Game", 1));

                        if (guess == magic) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! You Guessed the Magic Number!"
                                    + "\nThe Number is " + magic + "\nYou Made a Total of " + attempt5 + " attempt(s)", "Guessing Game", 1);
                        } else {
                            attempt4++;
                            if (guess > magic) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is higher than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0
                                );
                            } else {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is lower than the Hidden Number! Try Again!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                            }
                        }
                    } while (guess != magic);
                    if (attempt1 > attempt2) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 1 Won!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                    } else if (attempt2 > attempt3) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 2 Won!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                    } else if (attempt3 > attempt1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 3 Won!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                    } else if (attempt4 > attempt3) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 4 Won!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                    } else if (attempt5 > attempt4) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 4 Won!", "Guessing Game", 0);
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Such Gamemode", "Guessing Game", 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) Don't mix command line and rich client GUI.  It rarely works out well.

Comment: *my professor said something about making this a "loop within a loop" instead of copy-paste if else* listen to your teacher.... just take a look to nested loops, will be harder to figure it out, but you code will be reduced to 20% of actual size

Comment: Decompose your solution, do not *cram everything* on the Earth into a *single* `main()` method.

Comment: Yeah thats what i actually want. the nested loops are a bit too coomplicated but i actually want it rather than the copy paste if else. but idk how to do it....

Comment: how to decompose? sorry we're still in basic java

Comment: After assigning ``players`` you are checking in an ``if``-``else`` cascade if it is 2 or 3, for any other value it just falls through the code blocks and the program terminates.
btw. you aren't correctly dealing with the user input - what if the user chooses a number out of the specified range, types alphabetic characters or cancels the input query dialog? And ``magic`` should be ``(int) (Math.random() * 9) + 1;`` to match the range 1-10.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman `Math.random()` is exclusive, meaning that `Math.random() * 9` will never return 9.

Comment: @Marco de Zeeuw, yes I made a mistake. I usually just stick with [``java.util.Random``](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), it has handy methods and you can set the seed in the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you're missing an `}` after

```
else if (attempt3 > attempt1) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 3 Won!", "Guessing Game", 0);
}
```

and after

```
else if (attempt4 > attempt3) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 4 Won!", "Guessing Game", 0);
}
```

Edit: Removed the methods. Instead of having a lot of copy-paste code, you can use a loop for each player:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int guess;
    int magic = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    // Note that attemps are now initialized as 0
    int attempt1 = 0;
    int attempt2 = 0;
    int attempt3 = 0;
    int attempt4 = 0;
    int attempt5 = 0;
    // Or an int-array for attempts
    int players;

    // Get the amount of players
    do {
        players = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Number of Players. \n2-5 Only"));
        // Notify user if players < 2 || > 5
    } while (players < 2 || players > 5);

    // Play game for each player
    int player = 0;
    do {
        // Logic for a single player here, namely:
        // Increase the attempt based on the player, if you
        // know what an int-array is, use this. Always increase the
        // attempt, because a succesfull attempt is still an attempt.
        // Request input
        // Check if the guess equals the magic number
        // Notify the user
        player++;
    } while (player < players);

    // Notify winner based on lowest attempt, but only if attempt > 0.
    // This is why I've initialized attempts as 0.
}
```

Comment: "we need to create this program using only javax.swing,do-while,and if else." - sadly, methods are not mentioned...

Comment: Ouch. In that case there's not much to decompose. I'll edit the answer so that it won't have methods.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so our proffesor removed the 5 players and made it 3 instead. The '  ' on the part of else if(players=='3') makes the program ignore the userinput, when i removed the ' ' on the player number, it worked. here's the fully functional code for the 3 player program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            int guess;
            int magic = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);
            int attempt1 = 1;
            int attempt2 = 1;
            int attempt3 = 1;
            int players;

            players = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Number of Players. \n2-3 Only"));
            if(players == 2)
            {
                do
                {
                guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                       "Player 1, Enter A Number from 1-10","Guessing Game",1));

                if(guess == magic)
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! You Guessed the Magic Number!" +
                           "\nThe Number is " + magic + "\nYou Made a Total of " + attempt1 + " attempt(s)","Guessing Game",1);
                else
                {
                attempt1++;
                if(guess < magic)
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is higher than the Hidden Number! Try Again!"
                           ,"Guessing Game",0
                           );
                else
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is lower than the Hidden Number! Try Again!"
                           ,"Guessing Game",0);
                }
                }while(guess != magic);

            do
            {
            guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                   "Player 2, Enter A Number from 1-10","Guessing Game",1));

            if(guess == magic)
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! You Guessed the Magic Number!" +
                       "\nThe Number is " + magic + "\nYou Made a Total of " + attempt2 + " attempt(s)","Guessing Game",1);
            else
            {
            attempt2++;
            if(guess < magic)
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is higher than the Hidden Number! Try Again!"
                       ,"Guessing Game",0
                       );
            else
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is lower than the Hidden Number! Try Again!"
                       ,"Guessing Game",0);
            }
            }while(guess != magic);
            if(attempt1<attempt2)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 1 Won with " + attempt1 + "attempts"
                       ,"Guessing Game",0);
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 2 Won  Won with " + attempt2 + "attempts"
                       ,"Guessing Game",0);
            }


    else if(players == 3)
            {
                do
                {
                guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                       "Player 1, Enter A Number from 1-10","Guessing Game",1));

                if(guess == magic)
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! You Guessed the Magic Number!" +
                           "\nThe Number is " + magic + "\nYou Made a Total of " + attempt1 + " attempt(s)","Guessing Game",1);
                else
                {
                attempt1++;
                if(guess < magic)
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is higher than the Hidden Number! Try Again!"
                           ,"Guessing Game",0
                           );
                else
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is lower than the Hidden Number! Try Again!"
                           ,"Guessing Game",0);
                }
                }while(guess != magic);

            do
            {
            guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                   "Player 2, Enter A Number from 1-10","Guessing Game",1));

            if(guess == magic)
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! You Guessed the Magic Number!" +
                       "\nThe Number is " + magic + "\nYou Made a Total of " + attempt2 + " attempt(s)","Guessing Game",1);
            else
            {
            attempt2++;
            if(guess < magic)
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is higher than the Hidden Number! Try Again!"
                       ,"Guessing Game",0
                       );
            else
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is lower than the Hidden Number! Try Again!"
                       ,"Guessing Game",0);
            }
            }while(guess != magic);

            do
            {
            guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                   "Player 3, Enter A Number from 1-10","Guessing Game",1));

            if(guess == magic)
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! You Guessed the Magic Number!" +
                       "\nThe Number is " + magic + "\nYou Made a Total of " + attempt3 + " attempt(s)","Guessing Game",1);
            else
            {
            attempt3++;
            if(guess < magic)
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is higher than the Hidden Number! Try Again!"
                       ,"Guessing Game",0
                       );
            else
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! The number you gave is lower than the Hidden Number! Try Again!"
                       ,"Guessing Game",0);
            }
            }while(guess != magic);

            if(attempt1 < attempt2)
                if(attempt1 < attempt3)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 1 Won with " + attempt1 + "attempts"
                       ,"Guessing Game",0);
            else if(attempt2 < attempt3)
                if(attempt2 < attempt1)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 2 Won with " + attempt2 + "attempts"
                       ,"Guessing Game",0);
            else if(attempt3 < attempt2)
                if(attempt3 < attempt1)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 3 Won with " + attempt3 + "attempts"
                       ,"Guessing Game",0);
            }
}
```

}